# Controlling Oracle cursors

Tags: java, oracle

**The problem: Number of cursors go up until max is reached.**

First connection is created. **This connection is never close()ed**

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, schema, password);

con.setAutoCommit(true);
con.setHoldability(ResultSet.CLOSE_CURSORS_AT_COMMIT);
```

Using that same connection, client can

```
public ResultSet runSelect(final StringBuilder query) {

    Statement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    try {
        stmt = con.createStatement();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(query.toString());
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        logger.error("Failed to execute database query (select):" + query, e);
    }

    return rs;
}
```

Upon receiving the result, client `close()`es it together with a statement

```
        if (rs != null) {
            try {
                rs.close();
                ...
```

Is there something in here which would cause number of cursors to go up?

I am thinking it might be me missing to close stmt and should be

```
        if (rs != null) {
            try {
                Statement stmt = rs.getStatement();

                stmt.close();
                rs.close();
                ...
```

**Additionally, on the order in which Result Set is closed .. Is is ok to close the statement before closing the result set?**

Unfortunately i can't confirm this until tomorrow. What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

[Javadoc for Statement.close()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#close%28%29):

> When a Statement object is closed, its current ResultSet object, if
>   one exists, is also closed.

So you should either close the `ResultSet` first and then the `Statement`, or close only the `Statement`.

Also, close the `ResultSet` and/or `Statement` in a `finally` block.

Comment: You sholud never _"only close the `Statement`"_. This introduces bad coding habits, and is dangerous in some circumstances. Read [my answer in another thread to see why](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10923131/1344008).

Comment: @npe Do you say this because of some problems you had with statement.close? "You should never" seems pretty harsh for something that javadoc says it's safe to do.

Comment: Yes, closing wrapped connection on JBoss used to not close statements/resultsets. It just released the connection back to the pool. I don't now how it works now, it was on JBoss 5.0 GA